# How to get asnum and org values for the IP address with lua-geoip?

Tags: lua, geoip

I am using the [lua-geoip](https://github.com/agladysh/lua-geoip) library.

How do I use "geoip asnum" and "geoip org" to get the asnum and org value from ipaddress using lua script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you're looking to get an Autonomous System Number and ISP Organization for an IP address.

These values are stored in two databases: GeoIPASNum.dat and GeoIPOrg.dat. (Note that ASN number already contains an organization name, which may be sufficient for your purposes, for example: "AS15169 Google Inc.".)

At this moment the lua-geoip (v0.1.2) does not support either of these files.

You may add this support by cloning the country db, replacing `country` with `asnum` in the text.

https://github.com/agladysh/lua-geoip/blob/master/src/country.c

Then change query functions to use `GeoIP_org_by_name` instead of `GeoIP_id_by_name` — and push the result as a string, not country_info.

The process should be similar for the org DB should you need it.

See usage here:

https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c/blob/master/test/test-geoip-asnum.c
https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c/blob/master/test/test-geoip-org.c

*(Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of lua-geoip)*